# prometheus incorrect windows disk latency

Tags: prometheus

I am trying to monitor Windows disk latency using windows_exporter.
I tested disk performance using two commands below :

```
c:\> diskspd.exe -c1G -d120 -b4K -o32 -t4 -w10 -L -D -Suw testfile.dat
PS c:\> Get-Counter -ComputerName win-node -Counter '\LogicalDisk(*)\Avg. Disk sec/Read','\LogicalDisk(*)\Avg. Disk sec/Write' -SampleInterval 1
```

The output of both commands shows average latency of 11 msec.
While the prometheus query `rate(windows_logical_disk_read_write_latency_seconds_total[20s])` prints 125

Why this difference ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer on Prometheus Users group. This is the correct query :

> rate(windows_logical_disk_read_write_latency_seconds_total[10s]) /
> (rate(windows_logical_disk_reads_total[10s]) +
> rate(windows_logical_disk_writes_total[10s]))